# Not loading any documents from paginated collection

Tags: node.js, pagination, meteor

I am trying to paginate a collection using the [meteor-pages package](https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages), but when implemented as the basic usage suggested, doesn't show any document.

My meteor app has the following directory structure:

- server folder:  -- server.js
- client folder: 
  -- client.js 
  -- client.html
- common.js

In common.js:

`PassatemposBD = new Meteor.Collection("passatempos");
 Pages = new Meteor.Pagination("PassatemposBD");`

Then, in server.js I fill this collection with documents which I fetch from the web (takes around 30 seconds to fill). Then I publish it:

```
Meteor.publish('passatempos', function() {
    return PassatemposBD.find({});
});
```

In client.js:

```
Meteor.subscribe('passatempos');
```

In client.html

```
<body>
   <div> Passatempos:</div>
   {{> PassatemposBD}}
</body>
<template name="PassatemposBD">
   {{> pages}}
   {{> pagesNav}}  <!--Bottom navigation-->
</template>
```

When I run the app, it displays for a brief time (1 second or less) the rotating spin, then simply doesn't show nothing, neither the navigation below. In the browser console there is no error, neither there are errors in the server side.

Why is it not showing the pages of collection and the paginated items?

Answer (score 0):

The `collection-name` in the meteor-pages docs is the string passed into `new Meteor.Collection`, not the name of the variable which holds the collection. So your template should be called `passatempos`, not `PassatemposBD`.

Comment: I have already tried to change the template to passatempos, but still it doesn't show any item of the collection. I'm afraid that as I have the Meteor.Pagination creation ocurring at the same time as the creation of the collection (in common.js), and as the collection takes around 30 seconds to be filled in the server, it takes the empty collection and serve it to the template. Any tip on how to solve this?